# Number of kernel threads = cores?

Tags: kernel

I wonder whether or not a systems max kernel threads are determined by how many cores your CPU has. Or is it decided in another way?

Comment: Its based on the number of cores the physical device has.

Comment: The same question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux)

Comment: @Nacereddine but I'm not talking about how many threads you can create for a process. That would be user threads right? I'm asking about how many kernel threads (that is operated and scheduled by the OS kernel)

Comment: @starcorn Sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 5):

No, you can set the maximum kernel threads to very high numbers.

Note that the word "threads" is used for many different things:

- Most programmers use it to refer to independent threads of execution in the sense of POSIX threads. This is a way of organising programs and does not depend on hardware support. See [Maximum number of threads per process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux/344292#344292)
- Intel use it to refer to their "Hyperthreading" technology. See [Why does my Intel i7-920 display 8 cores instead of 4 cores?](https://superuser.com/questions/96001/why-does-my-intel-i7-920-display-8-cores-instead-of-4-cores) and [What does "thread" mean as related to CPUs?](https://superuser.com/q/340918/52492)

It may be that Intels use causes confusion.

---

Update re kernel threads

Here are some Linux kernel threads running in CoLinux under Vista on AMD Athlon 64 X2 dual-core.

```
$ ps -eLf
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0     1  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 init [2]
root         2     0     2  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2     3  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4     2     4  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [events/0]
root         5     2     5  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
root        21     2    21  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/0]
root        22     2    22  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [kseriod]
root        41     2    41  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [pdflush]
root        42     2    42  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [pdflush]
root        43     2    43  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root        44     2    44  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [aio/0]
root       727     2   727  0    1 17:24 ?        00:00:00 [kjournald]
```

**LWP** is the thread ID.

(See `man ps`: "-L Show **threads**, possibly with LWP and NLWP columns" … "LWP lwp (light weight process, or **thread**) ID of the lwp being reported. (alias spid, **tid**)")

kthreadd is the kernel thread daemon, I believe is is responsible for all the other kernel threads. Note I am not showing daemons like klogd which do not execute in ring 0 (as far as I know).

**Number of kernel threads != number of CPU cores.** (ref title of question)

---

> Kernel threads consist of a set of registers, a stack, and
>   a few corresponding kernel data structures.

…

> The purported advantage of kernel threads over processes
>   is faster creation and context switching compared
>   with processes.

…

> Kernel threads are considered “lightweight,” and one
>   would expect the number of threads to only be limited by
>   address space and processor time

…

> In particular, operating system kernels tend to see kernel
>   threads as a special kind of process rather than a unique entity.
>   For example, in the Solaris kernel threads are called
>   “light weight processes” (**LWP**’s). Linux actually creates
>   kernel threads using a special variation of fork called
>   “clone,” and until recently gave each thread a separate process
>   ID. Because of this heritage, in practice kernel threads
>   tend to be closer in memory and time cost to processes than
>   user-level threads,

([Multiple Flows of Control in Migratable Parallel Programs](http://lawlor.cs.uaf.edu/~olawlor/papers/2006/migthread/lawlor_migthread_2006.pdf) 2006)

Comment: that does not sound right, or maybe I got it wrong? Kernel threads are costly and not as easy created as user threads. User threads are supported by using APIs such as Java threads and POSIX you mention. Kernel thread are not the same thing as it. Kernel thread process these user threads. Actually kernel threads sees threads in a process as a single unit although if the process contains alot of threads. So still my question is not answered I think.

Comment: "kernel threads are part of kernel, which gets executed by linux scheduler like a real(userland) thread." - http://kerneltrap.org/node/20903

Comment: @starcom: see updated answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Current Linux kernels (and corresponding glibc) create a kernel task for each user thread. Internally the kernel uses several tasks for handling events asynchronously, those don't ever run in userspace. The "kernel threads" could mean the later, or just the kernel's view of an userspace thread (some systems, notably older Solaris, created user threads  ("lightweight processes"), and then mapped several of those to a kernel thread (somewhat like the pure userland threads implementations Linux used in the beginning). Murky naming ;-)